# When can std::thread::join fail due to no_such_process

Tags: c++, multithreading

[`std::thread::join()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) is permitted to fail, throwing a `std::system_error` for `no_such_process` if the thread is "not valid". Note that the `no_such_process` case is distinct from a thread that is not joinable (for which the error code is `invalid_argument`).

In what circumstances might that happen? Alternatively, what must I do to ensure that `join()` does not fail for that reason? I want a destructor to `join()` some threads it manages, and of course I want the destructor to never throw exceptions. What can make a (properly constructed and not destroyed) thread "not valid".

Comment: `ESRCH` means essentially invalid thread ID; if you get an `ESRCH` from an `std::thread::join()` (which should manage its own thread ID internally) your program status is probably already FUBAR, no point in trying to stop the rightful course of `std::terminate()`. The only case I can imagine this happening is either someone in your program obtaining the thread id and waiting on it (or detaching it) independently from `std::thread::join()`/`std::thread::detach()` - besides of course memory corruption.

Comment: May be try to check `std::thread::joinable()` before calling `std::thread::join()`

Comment: looking at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/system_error - it has an example of trying to detach a default constructed thread.  I've not tried it, but I'd expect swapping detach with join will have the same effect.

Comment: @UKMonkey: No, that produces `invalid_argument`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `no_such_process` error code corresponds to a `ESRCH` POSIX error code. On a POSIX system `std::thread::join()` probably delegates to [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html).

- Issue 7 of POSIX removed the possibility of an `ESRCH`.
- On Linux, [`pthread_join`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) may give `ESRCH` if no thread with the given thread ID could be found. The ID of a C++ thread is private data, so the only way the ID could be not found would be if `this` does not point to a properly constructed `std::thread`.

I conclude that this error condition can only occur as a result of an earlier action that had undefined behaviour, such as a bad `reinterpret_cast` or use of a dangling pointer.

Comment: ID of a C++ thread is private data, but in theory, it might happen that there is no thread of execution having such an ID.

Comment: I got this error when I had a program with a `static` variable containing a `thread` member be run by `afl-fuzz` (but not when executed normally). I suspect that this was because of the `fork()` done by `afl-fuzz` (which kind of made the actual thread "disappear" from the new (child) process, while the `thread` variable was still there, with `joinable()` being true but `join()` throwing this error).

Answer (score 4):

> In what circumstances might that happen?

On *nix systems, it happens when you try to join a thread whose ID is not in the thread table, meaning the thread does not exist (anymore). This might happen when a thread has already been joined and terminated, or if your thread variable's memory has been corrupted.

> Alternatively, what must I do to ensure that join() does not fail for that reason?

You might test `std::thread::joinable()`, but it might also fail<sup>1</sup>. Just don't mess with your thread variables, and you're good to go. Simply ignore this possibility, if you encounter such an error your program better core dump and let you analyse the bug.

---

<sub><sup>1)</sup> By *fail*, I mean report `true` instead of `false` or the other way around, not throw or crash.</sub>

Comment: I got this error when I had a program with a `static` variable containing a `thread` member be run by `afl-fuzz` (but not when executed normally). I suspect that this was because of the `fork()` done by `afl-fuzz` (which kind of made the actual thread "disappear" from the new (child) process, while the `thread` variable was still there, with `joinable()` being true but `join()` throwing this error).